# Powershell command works from cmd but not run

Tags: windows-7, powershell-2.0

I am trying to bind this command to a key (MS Keyboard Center):

```
powershell -Command "(new-object system.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://spotify.hum?command=play','test')"
```

If I run this from an unprivileged `cmd` all works well.  If I run it from Start / Run, I see the ps window open briefly but the action does not fire.

Same if I bind it to a key.  The absence of feedback makes it difficult to diagnose.

Is this something to do with execution policy?

Comment: @user193661 No, but the `cmd` shell is unprivileged, so the command doesn't require elevation.

Comment: I think you need to be admin to set execution policy. But you can use `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`. Or `-verb RunAs -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Comment: @user193661 Thanks for your help, it turned out that if I had run this as admin, it would probably have worked, but not for good reason - see the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `DownloadFile` location.  From `cmd`, it was open in a folder I can write to.

With `Start \ Run` it was running from `c:` root.

This was worked out by using the `-noexit` parameter, so the PS window stayed around to show the error.  The error message didn't show the reason, but seeing that there was at least an error to see helped.

Always use absolute paths kids.